# Defining Liquid tag, returning string works but processing to return string doesn't?

Tags: ruby, exception, jekyll, liquid, argument-error

I'm new to Liquid, but not to Ruby, and I know that Liquid isn't necessarily Ruby for safety reasons. However, in a Jekyll Blog, I tried to define the following code as a plugin:

```
module Jekyll
  class Person_Index < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @text = text
    end

    def render(context)
      for person in context.registers[:site].data["people"]

        if (person.index.to_s() == @text.to_s())
            return person.display
        end    
      end

      # We reach here, something's wrong anyway
      return "(( INDEX NOT FOUND #{@text} ))"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('Person_Index', Jekyll::Person_Index)
```

This, unsurprisingly, fails during document generation. Calling it as `{% Person_Index 2 %}` gives me this error:

```
Liquid Exception: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) in _posts/2014-07-22-an-entry.md/#excerpt
```

I'm sure someone's thinking "maybe it somehow got caught by the buggy excerpt generation". I tried that workaround by simply rewriting it with a second paragraph as a test case ; it still gives the same error, it's just not in #excerpt anymore.

A direct change to render to make it a one liner will make it run without any hesitation, and output "just fine" (I say that in quotes because it's not the desired behavior):

```
    def render(context)
      return "HOW ARE YOU BECAUSE I AM A POTATO"
    end
```

Where the tag is called, that will output the line lifted from Portal 2 just fine. (Yes, I know `return` is unnecessary in ruby, to each his own.)

**Why does the first one fail and the second one work? Is there a way to do what the first one seems to want to do?**

`_data/people.yml` is defined similar to:

```
-   index: 1
    nick:    Guy
    display: That Guy
    name:
        first:  That
        middle: One
        last:   Guy
    account:
        github: greysondn

-   index: 2
    nick:    Galt
    display: Johnny
    name:
        first:  John
        middle: 
        last:   Galt
    account:
        github:
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spotted the problem :

```
if (person.index.to_s() == @text.to_s())
  return person.display
end
```

Here your code tries to use **index** method on **person**. `person.['index'].to_s()` is better. Same for `person.display => person['display']`

Once here you still have a problem with `person.index.to_s() == @text.to_s()`. As your liquid tag is `{% Person_Index 2 %}`, `@text` is "2 " with a space.
So "2" != "2 ". We need to strip strings :

```
if (person['index'].to_s().strip == @text.to_s().strip)
```

is good but I prefer

```
if (person['index'].to_i() == @text.to_i())
    return person['display']
end
```

Comment: `person.index.to_s()`, where `index` is accessed as *attribute* I think..? (Your solution says *parameter*, a petty difference of meanings but future readers may get confused if I'm correct.)

Other than that, this is the correct solution. I took the advice to cast to integer (using `to_i()`) for the comparison, and it works like a charm now.

Thank you for your help, David!

Comment: Addendum: `person` is a `hash`, so we need to give it the key to get back the value. I tried to treat it like an arbitrary object. I'm not sure if Ruby has a nomenclature for such access. 
That is the reason for the change from `person.display` to `person['display']` - we must give it as a key, not try to access it as a value.

The advice about stripping is sound; I tested it out but didn't try stripping down (as cast to integer made sense)... I can't think of other notes that may be useful to future people here...